# Что означает такая запись после return C++. Зачем нужны первые скобки?

Tags: c++

```
Test_Type Func( Test_Type test, bool test_bool)
{return (Test_Type)(test | unsigned(test_bool));}
```

Comment: Первые тут предназначены для списка параметров. А еще есть фигурные для тела функции, круглые для приведения типа, для изменения порядка выполнения операций, и еще раз для еще одного приведения типа...

Comment: `(Test_Type)` - это приведение типа.

Comment: Это C-style cast https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast В С++ использовать его не стоит